# Xamarin.android - Copy .jpg to shared folder

Tags: file, xamarin.android, jcifs

I'm using a Samba File Server for copy files from my Android device to a shared folder on Windows. With .txt files i haven't any problems, works fine, but I tried to copy a .jpg file into shared folder and it fails. I searched a lot of codes from internet but anyone solved my problem.
I managed to copy the image, but when I open it, is damaged.

Does anyone have any sample code?

My code is this:

```
Java.IO.File mfile = new Java.IO.File(item.FullName);

var mSharedFolderCalidad = new SmbFile(AppGlobalConfigSoftware.Instance.Parameters.PathToDownloadCalidad + item.Name);

//If exists don't create another time
if (!mSharedFolderCalidad.Exists())
     mSharedFolderCalidad.CreateNewFile();

InputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(mfile);

SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(mSharedFolderCalidad);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = inFile.Read(buf)) > 0) 
{
  sfos.Write(buf, 0, len);
}

inFile.Close();
sfos.Close();
```

All help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code routines that you are using right now, and please add more context to the question.

Comment: I added my code on top. the context is: I took a photo with my device and i want to upload the photo into the shared folder.

Comment: Hi, thank you! it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Media.Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) from nuget to take photo firstly.

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
});
```

```
public  byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

`MediaFile` has `GetStream().`

You could use this to the Stream and then convert that to a byte[]. Here is one way to do that:

#### Define a stream

```
Stream imageStream;
```

#### And init it after you take the photo .

```
imageStream = file.GetStream();

var imageArr= ReadFully(imageStream );
```

And then write it to your folder .