# How to save photos from gallery to shared folder on a windows server in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to save an image from the Android gallery to a shared folder on a windows server. With the NuGet SharpCifs.Std package installed, I try to use the **CopyTo** method to save the image but it gives an error when the path is correct to my knowledge.

This is the error

[image: https://ibb.co/2v0BrqD]

Piece of code ...

```
using SharpCifs.Smb;
...
...
var windowsAuth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("mydomain.local", "user", "password");
var source = new SmbFile(photoFile);
var dest = new SmbFile(photosPath, windowsAuth);
source.CopyTo(dest);
```

In debug mode, the value of variables are:

*source = file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.salicru/files/Pictures/temp/IMG_20190828_101004_88.jpg*

*dest = file://srvdoc/compartit/fotos equips/M3/6A0BW000001/*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here is a similar issue maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57709184/xamarin-android-copy-jpg-to-shared-folder

Comment: Thanks Lucas, you link aswer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a method that I called ConvertMediaFileToByteArray for the conversion of the photo stream to a byte[].

```
private byte[] ConvertMediaFileToByteArray(MediaFile file)
{
     using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
          file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
          return memoryStream.ToArray();
     }
 }
```

Converting call.

```
file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
{
    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small
});

if (file != null)
{
   imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
   {
       var stream = file.GetStream();
       file.Dispose();
       return stream;
   });

   //Convert ImatgeStream to BYTE[]
   var imageToByte = ConvertMediaFileToByteArray(file);
}
```

Then, instead of using CopyTo method i used CreateNewFile method.

```
var windowsAuth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain", "admin", "password");
var dest = new SmbFile(photosPath + imageName, windowsAuth);

dest.CreateNewFile();
var writeStream = dest.GetOutputStream();
writeStream.Write(imageToByte);
writeStream.Dispose();
```