# Xamarin - Is there a similar framework to Photokit (iOS) available for Android, or a good way to get the filestream of all images in the gallery?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently creating a Xamarin Forms app where I'm looking to retreive all the images from the device gallery and display them in a grid. I want to do this using DepdencyService with native implementations.

For iOS I use the Photokit framework to retreive the Stream of each image and feed this into my grid.

I'm looking for a way to solve this similarly for Android. I've tried looking through docs but can't seem to find something that does this.

The view

```
 private void GetGallery()
        {
            var imageStreams = DependencyService.Get<IGalleryFetcher>().GalleryStream();

            foreach (var stream in imageStreams)
            { 
               // Create image objects and set the stream as the image source
            }
```

The iOS implementation

```
 public ObservableCollection<Stream> GalleryStream()
        {
            var streamArray = new ObservableCollection<Stream>();
            PHFetchResult fetchResult = PHAsset.FetchAssets(PHAssetMediaType.Image, null);
            for (int i = 0; i < fetchResult.Count(); i++)
            {
                PHAsset phAsset = (PHAsset)fetchResult[i];
                string fileName = (NSString)phAsset.ValueForKey((NSString)"filename");

                PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageData(phAsset, null, (data, dataUti, orientation, info) =>
                {
                    var path = (info?[(NSString)@"PHImageFileURLKey"] as NSUrl).FilePathUrl.Path;
                    Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    streamArray.Add(stream);

                });
            }
            return streamArray;
        }
```

Android implementation

```
//Help needed
```

Is there any available framework or package that can help with doing something similar for Android as I've done for iOS?

EDIT:
I use the CrossMedia plugin for taking and selecting images, but I can not find that this plugin provides the desired feature.

My desired functionality is that geting all the images from the gallery does not require an active action or selection. No file picker or import action, the (file)stream for every image should be retreived automatically when the view is opened.

Comment: Check  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin . This is a simple cross platform plugin to take photos and video or pick them from a gallery from shared code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LucasZhang-MSFT, I should have mentioned that I have used this plugin, but I can't find a way for it to solve what I'm trying to do (Automatically retreiving the stream of every image on the device gallery and showing them in a view, without any interaction or active selection required).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57709184/xamarin-android-copy-jpg-to-shared-folder/57712050#57712050

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I might be struggling to see the solution here, but as far as I can see this still requires that the app prompts with a file picker, and requires manual selection of images, correct? 

I might not be explaining it clearly. The desired outcome is a grid-layout that imports your gallery images without any active action taken (e.g. such as the Instagram layout when publishing posts)

Comment: Sflovik you are explaining it perfectly. It's like people dont read the question, and just posts a link to something else. I'm also looking for a way to load all photos from gallery. That is, NOT A PICKER. But can't find anything about it. Everywhere is just links to the same nuget-packages with photopickers. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **ContentResolver** in Android .

Add the following permission in `Manifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

#### in your DepdencyService

```
void GetAllImage()
{
   Android.Net.Uri imageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri;
   var carsor = ContentResolver.Query(imageUri,null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MimeType + "=? or "+ MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MimeType+ "=?",new string[] { "image/jpeg", "image/png" }, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DateModified);

   while(carsor.MoveToNext())
   {
     string path = carsor.GetString(carsor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data));
     Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     streamArray.Add(stream);
   }

}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much!

On a related note in case anyone finds this: consider retrieving the path strings instead and create imagesources as needed from the file path.

Answer (score 3):

Summary of solution for anyone interested.

Per the answer from @Lucas Zhanf - MSFT , this is the final solution.

Android - GalleryFetcherAndroid

```
   public ObservableCollection<string> GalleryStream()
        {
            var gallerySources = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Android.Net.Uri imageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri;

            var cursor = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(imageUri, null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MimeType + "=? or " + MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MimeType + "=?", new string[] { "image/jpeg", "image/png" }, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DateModified);

            while (cursor.MoveToNext())
            {
                string path = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data));
                gallerySources.Add(path);
            }

            return gallerySources;
        }
```

iOS - GalleryFetcheriOS

```
  public ObservableCollection<string> GalleryStream()
        {
            var streamArray = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            PHFetchResult fetchResult = PHAsset.FetchAssets(PHAssetMediaType.Image, null);
            for (int i = 0; i < fetchResult.Count(); i++)
            {
                PHAsset phAsset = (PHAsset)fetchResult[i];
                string fileName = (NSString)phAsset.ValueForKey((NSString)"filename");

                PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageData(phAsset, null, (data, dataUti, orientation, info) =>
                {
                    var path = (info?[(NSString)@"PHImageFileURLKey"] as NSUrl).FilePathUrl.Path;
                    streamArray.Add(path);

                });
            }
            return streamArray;
        }
```

Forms interface - IGalleryFetcher

```
    public interface IGalleryFetcher
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> GalleryStream();
    }
```

Example usage - ContentPage

```
  private void GetGallery()
        {
            var imageSources = DependencyService.Get<IGalleryFetcher>().GalleryStream();
            foreach (var imageSource in imageSources)
            {
                //Consider applying a limitation to the amount of images to load
                ImageSource source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageSource);
                //Use the image source for your view
            }
```

Comment: var path = (info?[(NSString)@"PHImageFileURLKey"] as NSUrl).FilePathUrl.Path;

is returning null for me. Any solution? using iPadOS and iOS 13.1

Comment: Check my answer if on iOS 13: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58332834/1700775